# How to change FireFox switch tab shortcut on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I change the keyboard shortcut to switch between next and previous tabs on Firefox on OS X?

Comment: Please accept the answer, I spent a considerable amount of time searching on Google, before it led me here (I was expecting a stackexchange answer from the start, but it took time until it surfaced).

Answer (score 29):

updated for macOS and current Firefox.

1. default shortcut: `Command`+`Option`+`⭠` and `Command`+`Option`+`⭢`
2. alternative shortcut: `Ctrl`+`Tab` and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Tab`
   this shows firefox tab switcher in current version
3. alternative shortcut: `Command`+`{` and `Command`+`}`
   this actually requires 3 keys to be pressed on US keyboard `Command`+`Shift`+`{` and `Command`+`Shift`+`}` and may not work with other keyboard languages
4. alternative shortcut: `Ctrl`+`Page Up` and `Ctrl`+`Page Down`
5. you can also jump to tabs directly with `Cmd`+`1`, `Cmd`+`2`, `Cmd`+`3`, `Cmd`+`4` etc.
6. you can try a Firefox add-on focused on switching tabs which suits your needs: [Add-ons browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?platform=mac&q=switch%20tabs)
7. just use a BetterTouchTool to remap any keystroke or mouse/trackpad gesture you want to already existing `Command`+`Option`+`⭠` and `Command`+`Option`+`⭢` keystrokes.

I personally prefer #7: `Command`+`Option`+`⭠` and `Command`+`Option`+`⭢` for switching tabs. I haven't modified Firefox at all and I used BetterTouchTool to remap keystrokes in every other app which uses other commands that these two. Now I can use `Cmd`+`Option`+`⭠` and `Command`+`Option`+`⭢` to switch tabs across all apps I use on Mac and it works great.

Comment: These work for me.  Not sure why it was downvoted.  You can also go directly to a tab by pressing cmd plus the number of the tab (ie, press cmd+1 to go straight to the first tab).

Comment: If my post answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted. You should accept answers every time it resolves your problem. By the way, what solution have you finally used?

Comment: Another non-acceptor... Probably abandoned the question... The most annoying thing that happens here... @Downvoter could be... Just my 2¢...

Comment: @ChrisHerbert: Although `cmd +#` is available, it is useless when you have 20 tabs open. You can ergonomically manage as many using e.g. [side tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/side-tabs/).

Comment: An observation: although 1 ships ready for use, it still requires that the 2nd hand leave the pad, defying the purpose of switching windows and tabs with only the left hand. So #5 with `Cmd +1` (previous) and `Cmd +2` proves to be the best solution, because it is also next to the closely related ``Cmd +` `` and `Cmd +tab`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of *changing* the Switch Tab keyboard shortcuts in macOS.

Comment: I wish it would match Safari, at least, since Safari and Chrome *mostly* match each other for basic web and tab navigation.

Safari also uses 'Shift+CMD+Arrow' to switch tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I use this addon on Firefox on MacOS: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs

However, I wanted to use `Command+Q` but Firefox wouldn't allow that because it's a built-in shortcut.
So I set a different shortcut: `Command+Shift+E` and then mapped `Command+Q` to that using Keyboard Maestro app.

[image]